# Automapper Ignore complex properties

Tags: c#, automapper

Im using Automapper v6.2 with profiles and Autofac to register those profiles, my Domain classes have properties that my Models does not have as I dont need them (For example an Id or other properties that only needs to be saved on my dB)

For example:

```
public class TurnoProfile : Profile
{
    public TurnoProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<Turnos, TurnoModel>()
            .ForMember(d => d.Id, s => s.MapFrom(src => src.Id))
            .ForMember(d => d.Descripcion, s => s.MapFrom(src => src.Descripcion));

        CreateMap<TurnoModel, Turnos>()
            .ForMember(d => d.Id, s => s.MapFrom(src => src.Id))
            .ForMember(d => d.Descripcion, s => s.MapFrom(src => src.Descripcion))
            .ForMember(d => d.Alumnos, s => s.Ignore());
    }
}
```

Domain object (EF 5)

```
public partial class Turnos
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public Turnos()
        {
            Alumnos = new HashSet<Alumnos>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string Descripcion { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Alumnos> Alumnos { get; set; }
    }
```

Model:

```
public class TurnoModel
{
    #region Fields
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Descripcion { get; set; } 
    #endregion
}
```

As you can see I dont want Alumnos to be mapped, this is a 1 to many relationship, I want to ignore which `Alumnos` have certain `Turnos`.

But I have the following error:

```
Unmapped members were found. Review the types and members below.
Add a custom mapping expression, ignore, add a custom resolver, or modify the source/destination type
For no matching constructor, add a no-arg ctor, add optional arguments, or map all of the constructor parameters
============================================================
TurnoModel -> Turnos (Destination member list)
Prog_II.Data.Model.TurnoModel -> Prog_II.Data.Domain.Turnos (Destination member list)

Unmapped properties:
Alumnos
```